# How to declare appcompat_v7 dependency in build.gradle within eclipse project setup?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, android-appcompat

I am using Eclipse with ADT and want to build my project with Gradle(2.3). The project structure is the standard generated android eclipse project structure.
I am using the android support library appcompat_7.
The support libraries are installed and everything I need from the Android SDK is up-to-date.
Here is my (failing) attempt to my build.gradle file (positioned at the root):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
}
}
```

I get the following BUILD FAILURE from gradle:

```
C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2>gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'training2'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@3e7545e8.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.663 secs
```

When I am leaving out the line about the appcompat dependency I get the following BUILD FAILURE:

```
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources
C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-22\android.jar -M C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.training2 -0 apk
Error Code:
1
Output:
C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

C:\Workspaces\EclipseAndroid\training2\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.567 secs
```

How should I declare the dependencies in order to get the project build?

In my opinion, this is a pretty basic question when you want to build an eclipse-android project with gradle, however I could not find a solution during my websearch, I hope you can help :)

Comment: There is no official support for building Android projects with Gradle in Eclipse: consider moving to Android Studio so that your command line build process will match the build process used in your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you aren't clearly separating the `buildscript` definition (i.e., where to find the correct plugin) vs the android specific definitions (which apply after the `apply plugin` line).

Therefore, the `buildscript` section cannot include dependencies on Android libraries (it is only for declaring where to find the plugin):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3' // <-- updated
    }
}
```

Next, the correct plugin for an Android application is `com.android.application`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Then there's three components to add after that: `repositories` (where to find Android libraries), `dependencies` (what Android dependencies you have), and `android` (where you configure Android build specifics):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' // <-- updated
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Put those three sections together and you'll have a complete `build.gradle` file that will work.